# Multiple headers/footers when using custom TeX in r bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

Loved bookdown. However, I'm porting my book from LaTeX into bookdown, and would like some help with headers/footers.

I have a custom code that generates headers and footers in my LaTeX:

```
% HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
 % for normal pages
 \nouppercaseheads
 \headsep = 0.16in
 \makepagestyle{mystyle}
 \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
 \makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
 \makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textls[100]{\textsf{\small\scshape\thetitle}}}{}
 \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textls[100]{\textsf{\small\scshape\leftmark}}}{}
 \makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\textls[100]{\textsf{\small\thepage}}}{}
 \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\textls[100]{\textsf{\small\thepage}}}{}
 \clearmark{section} % removing section in the headers
 \makeatletter
 \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
 \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
 \makeatother

 % for pages where chapters begin
 \makepagestyle{plain}
 \makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
 \makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
 \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}
 \pagestyle{mystyle}
% END HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
```

I placed my entire LaTeX preamble in `preamble.tex` (and I've not added content to the book just yet). It renders the following:

[image: How bookdown renders the LaTeX]

The render should actually look like this:

[image: The actual LaTeX render]

Also, here's what's in the YAML in `index.Rmd`.

```
documentclass: memoir
papersize: smalldemyvo
indent: yes
microtypeoptions:
  - protrusion
  - tracking
fontfamily: Alegreya
fontfamilyoptions:
  - osf
fontsize: 11pt
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    template: null
```

I'm new to bookdown, but I did read the documentation. I feel I need help with two things.

1. How do I remove the auto-generated headers and footers?
2. How do I make "Contents" disappear from the ToC *table*?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you might have to use not only the preamble.tex file but also a template.tex file. Maybe a before_body.tex file as well. See a [demo](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/_output.yml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, bookdown uses some built-in template(s). If you need more adjustments, you could make your own .tex files (preamble.tex, before_body.tex, after_body.tex, template.tex) and specify them in the yaml part of index.Rmd like this:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
    before_body: before_body.tex
    after_body: after_body.tex
template: template.tex
```

bookdown merges preamble.tex, before_body.tex, and after_body.tex with the main body (marked as `$body$` in template.tex) of your book into one .tex file in the structure under the control of template.tex, and compile it into a pdf book with pandoc and LaTex.

In your case, you have to insert your custom code into template.tex in the right way. @yihui's [demo](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/latex/template.tex) shows a good example.

For more examples to customize these .tex files, I would suggest that you could either look into the 'bookdownplus' package I developed, which gives you 19 examples showing how to tailor a LaTeX template into bookdown's frame, or read [Chapter 8.3 Create Your Own Templates in the bookdownplus textbook](https://bookdown.org/baydap/bookdownplus/advanced.html#customize).

Comment: Ah, the TeX/LaTeX thing repeats! :)
I'm marking this as the answer since the tutorial provides more information to users looking for it.

Comment: Glad it helps. BTW, could you kindly change the citation of my nickname 'dapeng' as my real name 'pzhao'? I changed it in my profile and found the citation was not updated automatically. But it cannot be changed back in 30 days.

Comment: Done! It still doesn't link you, though.

Answer (score -1):

**Edited answer**

bookdown has built-in templates (decided mostly by `documentclass` and/or Pandoc). Refer the [Theming](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/theming.html) and [Templates](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html) sections of bookdown documentation.

An example to learn from, as @pzhao suggested, is the [template in the bookdown-chinese](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/latex/template.tex) repo. Observe the variables that bring in data from the Rmd files. They're enclosed between `$$`, such as `$body$`. [`_output.yml`](https://github.com/yihui/bookdown-chinese/blob/master/_output.yml) has a reference to this template. This way, you override the default template, thereby eliminating duplicate headers/footers. Your LaTeX template decides what forms part of your headers/footers. An example is the LaTeX code in my question.

The appearance of `Contents` in the ToC table can also be controlled by tweaking your custom LaTeX template. I use the `memoir` class, and help to remove self-reference can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/how-to-remove-double-contents-heading-generated-by-memoir). My custom LaTeX template already took care of it, so it fixed itself as soon as I figured out how to use my custom template.

Comment: Can you share any information about this template? It would help make the question more useful to other people who may encounter the same problem.

Comment: That's not an answer for the 2 questions asked. Just recommend a tutorial.

Comment: Edited. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeyHarper I will try giving an answer with more information which might help.

Comment: @MikeyHarper, here's the [repo with the customized code](https://github.com/theramiyer/bookdown-custom). Hope it helps.